# MadExcept Leak Report for Delphi

Tags: delphi

(Update: I've updated the question and removed some pictures)

I'm using MadExcept for leaks and I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with what the tool is reporting.

1. Here is my first question. I don't get why this one is reported as a leak:

[image]

Callstack for the Dynamic Memory:

```
allocation number: 526920
program up time: 21.98 s
type: DynamicArray
address: $211e4d00
size: 28
access rights: read/write
reference counter: 1
item count: 5
item size: 4

main thread ($6d9c):
671a7cc7 madExcept32.dll madExceptDbg           1746 GetMemCallback
00d8765f QX.exe          System                 4818 @ReallocMem
00d904ca QX.exe          System                 4818 DynArraySetLength
00d90631 QX.exe          System                 4818 @DynArraySetLength
01b7d2a3 QX.exe          kbmMemTable           17393 TkbmCustomStreamFormat.DetermineSaveFields
00ec42f5 QX.exe          System.Classes              TStream.SetPosition
01b7d7f6 QX.exe          kbmMemTable           17509 TkbmCustomStreamFormat.BeforeSave
0264fcb9 QX.exe          kbmMemCSVStreamFormat   560 TkbmCustomCSVStreamFormat.BeforeSave
01b75126 QX.exe          kbmMemTable           14331 TkbmCustomMemTable.InternalSaveToStreamViaFormat
01b74e97 QX.exe          kbmMemTable           14272 TkbmCustomMemTable.SaveToFileViaFormat
01b74eb3 QX.exe          kbmMemTable           14274 TkbmCustomMemTable.SaveToFileViaFormat
01b75a7c QX.exe          kbmMemTable           14571 TkbmCustomMemTable.SavePersistent
01b75b80 QX.exe          kbmMemTable           14591 TkbmCustomMemTable.SavePersistent
00d8760c QX.exe          System                 4818 @FreeMem
01b6ba03 QX.exe          kbmMemTable           10523 TkbmCustomMemTable.SetActive
010c94c4 QX.exe          Data.DB                     TDataSet.Close
010b7432 QX.exe          Data.DB                     TField.Destroy
00d8a930 QX.exe          System                 4818 TObject.Free
00ed94be QX.exe          System.Classes              TComponent.DestroyComponents
00ed8f47 QX.exe          System.Classes              TComponent.Destroy
00f6be75 QX.exe          Vcl.Controls                TControl.Destroy
00e3e6b9 QX.exe          madExcept                   InterceptClassDestroy
00ec05df QX.exe          System.Classes              TPersistent.Destroy
00f70c51 QX.exe          Vcl.Controls                TWinControl.Destroy
01060b13 QX.exe          Vcl.Forms                   TScrollingWinControl.Destroy
010620e1 QX.exe          Vcl.Forms                   TCustomForm.Destroy
01062100 QX.exe          Vcl.Forms                   TCustomForm.Destroy
00d8a930 QX.exe          System                 4818 TObject.Free
0274b08b QX.exe          ReportAdmin            4057 CDS_CheckAndImportReportFiles
043b1673 QX.exe          Reports                 184 TReports.LoadReports
044257a1 QX.exe          QX.Startup.Common      1174 StartupCode
0448568b QX.exe          QX                      638 initialization

memory dump: 
211e4d00  01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  ................
211e4d10  02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 - 04 00 00 00              ............
```

The supposed leak is pointing to this code where the `SetLength(SaveFields,nf);` is done:

```
procedure TkbmCustomStreamFormat.DetermineSaveFields(ADataset:TkbmCustomMemTable);
var
   i:TkbmNativeInt;
   nf:TkbmNativeInt;
begin
     // Setup flags for fields to save.
     with ADataset do
     begin
          nf:=Fieldcount;
          SetLength(SaveFields,nf);

          for i:=0 to nf-1 do
          begin
               // Default dont save this field.
               SaveFields[i]:=-1;

               // If a blob field, only save if specified.
               if (Fields[i].DataType in kbmBlobTypes) then
               begin
                    if not (sfSaveBlobs in sfBlobs) then continue;
                    SaveFields[i]:=i;
               end;

               // Only save fields of specific types.
               case Fields[i].FieldKind of
                    fkData,fkInternalCalc: if sfSaveData in sfData then SaveFields[i]:=i;
                    fkCalculated: if sfSaveCalculated in sfCalculated then SaveFields[i]:=i;
                    fkLookup: if sfSaveLookup in sfLookup then SaveFields[i]:=i;
                    else SaveFields[i]:=-1;
               end;

               // If not to save invisible fields, dont.
               if not (Fields[i].Visible or (sfSaveNonVisible in sfNonVisible)) then SaveFields[i]:=-1;
          end;
     end;
end;
```

But why is that? From my reading you don't have to reset Dynamic Arrays at the end.

Comment: If the memory leak report hints to code in that library it might be better to contact the author/vendor about it

Comment: You probably only have one source of the leak, and it may not be ANY of the things listed there. Trying to unravel this will drive you crazy. What's the EXCEPTION it's reporting? Show the WHOLE report, not just the parts you think are relevant. (Well, you don't need the dis-asm, the registers, etc. There's some info above and/or below what you showed that has clues.) Is it YOUR CODE that's causing this error? Or the Tkbm library? These reports can be really tricky to dial-in.

Comment: [So many pictures, so little text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: If the instance that owns the leaked arrays and strings is not itself destroyed, then the arrays and stings leak

Comment: If that were the case then madExcept would very likely also list that instance.

Comment: The real question is, why is `TkbmCustomMemTable` allocating memory to save data while it is being destroyed?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If this was an instance not freed MadExcept would indicate it as such. Those are the easy ones to find.  This though I don't get

Comment: Fix the dozens of other memory leaks first I would say - maybe this one goes away as well.

Comment: @StefanGlienke I fixed the ones below the highlighted item.  I just don't know what is going on with the highlighted one.

Comment: Write an MCVE and report it to the kbmMemTable vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is set to try to save its content during destruction of the component.
So I would think it is an artifact from MadExcept's detection, since it is probably not expecting anything to allocate memory during a destruction of a component.

Further I would suggest you to make your own conscious decision about when exactly the memtable is to save its contents, rather than waiting until application destruction.

Comment: To clarify, the madexcept report comes up only on closing of the app.  It is not that the "leak" is reported because the app is closing.  It's during the startup of the app already.

Ps I've sent you mail on the 4th about this issue as well.

Comment: I can see on the provided stack trace, that it is persisting data thru a streamstorage during destruction of the kbmMemTable component at the time of app shutdown.
So search there please.